# Format row if one or more cells contain a specified string

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

In excel 2007, I would like to apply a formatting rule throughout my entire workbook, which will format a row if and only if that row contains one or more cells with a question mark. I'm trying this formula:

```
=IF(countif(c2:l2, "?")>0)
```

Where row 1 contains a header, and the values that I would like to check should range from columns C to L. Excel says that there is an error however, can anyone see what that error is?

Comment: try to enter a full `IF` formula: `=IF(countif(c2:l2, "?")>0, TRUE, FALSE)`?

Comment: Thanks JMax, that's gotten me somewhere at least. But now, excel highlights the row whether the condition should be true, or not. Also, it only highlights part of the row, from column A to column J, while skipping the remaining columns. Currently, the rule formula reads `=IF(COUNTIF(C2:L2, "?")>0, TRUE, FALSE)`, and the selected range is `=$2:$30`.

Comment: Thanks pnuts, although the pattern has changed now, excel still seems to be highlighting rows at random (although entire rows now).

Comment: Yes, each time I'm trying a new one, I'll make sure that it's the only one (and I haven't been saving the spreadsheet while testing the different formulas).

Comment: Yes, for example, some of the extraneously highlighted rows contain only numbers, plain text, punctuation (periods and commas only), and the dollar sign ($).

Comment: Woops, sorry, just saw pnuts comment after I entered it as an answer.

Comment: @pnuts That seems to have made it much more selective in which rows are highlighted, although now, it's only highlighting three rows (which contain almost the same data, and happen to be right next to each other), although these three rows do not have any question marks in them.

Comment: Yes, like so: `=$2:$25`, which I believe takes care of rows 2 through 25. The last 4 rows are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "?" is a wildcard.  You need to escape it with a tilde:

```
=COUNTIF($C2:$L2, "~?")>0
```

Also, you didn't have absolute referencing for the columns.  Also, you don't need `IF` in a conditional format.  The "condition" is the IF.

Comment: Sadly, this answer replicates the most recent results; only three rows are highlighted now, all three not containing a question mark. Interestingly enough, I applied the format to rows 2 - 30, and for some reason, rows 28 and 29 are highlighted. They don't contain anything, nor do the 7 rows before it.

Comment: @pnuts, I'm sure your most recent comment is correct, and that the activecell isn't in row 2 when the CF is being applied.  On your question above, about the IF and first two columns, if the CF is applied to columns A and B, then they'll be highlighted if there's a question mark somewhere in column C to L.

Comment: @DougGlancy & pnuts: both of you would desserve upvotes for your implication - I think Doug's edited answer got to the point here

Comment: Well I'll be darned. It seems like selecting row 2, then applying the format worked. I thought it didn't matter when you selected that the entire workbook would be formatted. Thank you guys for the help!